# Geting rid of the 2 random dots on my image slider in Magento

Tags: css, magento, slider

I'm currently customising a site with Magento. I installed a wow-slider image slider. It works but it seems to have 2 random dots to the left and also a random space before the shadow.

Please see link
ellamatt.mygostore.co.uk

Please see here and let me know if you have an idea. I would give you the code but there are a few CSS and JS pages that go with this.

PS: it works properly in usual HTML but not in Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two dots are because of the `li` elements.

Changing the `list-style` property to none on this css rule will get rid of them:

**Old:**

```
.widget-static-block ul {
    list-style: disc outside none;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

**New:**

```
.widget-static-block ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

And, for the shadow, on the same css rule, add a height of zero and displaying it as inline will get the ul block out of the way and remove the space before the shadow.

**Final:**

```
.widget-static-block ul {
    display: inline;
    height: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh my Goodness Thank you soooo much!! It worked! I had tried a few things! I'm not a coder and have found a lot of issues and simply couldn't figure this out! I've changed it now, thanks.

Comment: Also, please is there a straight forward way to remove the shadows altogether without having to mess around too much with the .css? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Finally got vote-up privileges so thought I'd come back to pay my respect :)

Comment: Wow Lola, that's awesome! And congrats for the new privilege.